# Get raw voice input

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have enabled the google assistant in my api.ai and get the valid intent. However I would also want to get the voice print of the user and save users context with that voice print. is there a way to intercept this , where I can get the voice print ? Idea is to save the conversation with users voice.

Thanks

Comment: Currently there are no APIs which let developers get access to the actual audio that the user asked.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get the original audio recording of the users' request - just the transcript.  There is currently true for all the voice assistants: google assistant, alexa, and cortana.

Comment: Is there still no way ?